# Como usar o print para caracteres especiais em Python?

Tags: python, string

Ao tentar usar o print para um caractere especial, obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
print('\')

  File "<ipython-input-38-eaac87876c3b>", line 1
    print('\')
              ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: PS: o caractere especial é ( \ )

Comment: Thiago, bom dia! Adicione outro \, dessa forma `print('\\')`. Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

O caractere `\` tem significado especial em strings: ele é usado para [sequências de escape](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-22) (por exemplo, `\n` representa a quebra de linha, `\t` representa o TAB, etc).

E no caso, `\'` representa o próprio caractere `'`, já que é assim que eu faço para que o caractere `'` seja representado em uma string delimitada pelo próprio `'`. Ou seja, `print('\'')` irá imprimir um `'`.

Por isso deu erro, porque o primeiro `'` indica o início da string, e dentro dela tem `\'`, que significa "um caractere `'`", e como não há o fechamento da string, ocorre o erro.

Se quiser imprimir o próprio caractere `\`, este deve ser escrito como `\\`, assim:

```
print('\\')
```

Isto irá imprimir o caractere `\`.

Answer (score 1):

Experimente usar os códigos da tabela Unicode para imprimir esse ou qualquer outro caractere especial:

```
print('\u005C')
```

Você pode conferir as tabelas Unicode de vários caracteres especiais [aqui](http://www.unicode.org/charts):